# Rails 3 paperclip install, now get LoadError

Tags: paperclip

I am very new to Rails, I am running Rails 3
I recently installed ImageMagick via Homebrew and then ran 'sudo plugin install git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git'

I added "gem 'rmagick'" to my root Gemfile.

Immediately after doing so I found that no rails commands worked anymore (error below). I tried adding "config.gem "rmagick", :lib => "RMagick"" to my environment.rb as some other threads suggested, but this returns a different error (undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError))

Any thoughts?

```
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': no such file to load -- cocaine (LoadError)
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /Users/tonybeninate/Documents/Apps/PhotoBlog/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:43
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /Users/tonybeninate/Documents/Apps/PhotoBlog/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/railtie.rb:1
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /Users/tonybeninate/Documents/Apps/PhotoBlog/vendor/plugins/paperclip/rails/init.rb:1
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/plugin.rb:81
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
from /Users/tonybeninate/Documents/Apps/PhotoBlog/config/environment.rb:5
from /Users/tonybeninate/Documents/Apps/PhotoBlog/config.ru:3:in `require'
from /Users/tonybeninate/Documents/Apps/PhotoBlog/config.ru:3
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
from /Users/tonybeninate/Documents/Apps/PhotoBlog/config.ru:1:in `new'
from /Users/tonybeninate/Documents/Apps/PhotoBlog/config.ru:1
```

Comment: If it helps, you can view my app here: https://github.com/tbhockey/PhotoBlog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cloned your repo and ran the app but didn't get any of those errors. Have you tried installing paperclip as a gem instead of a plugin?

This is the setup I have working in one of my apps (using Amazon S3 for storage):

```
# Gemfile
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-s3'

#MyModel migration
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :my_model do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.string :image_file_name
      t.string :image_content_type
      t.integer :image_file_size
      t.datetime :image_updated_at

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


#MyModel.rb  
has_attached_file :image, 
 :storage => :s3, 
 :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/amazons3.yml",
 :path => "pictures/:id.:extension"


#config/amazons3.yml
development:
  access_key_id: MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  secret_access_key: MY_SECRET_KEY
  bucket: myBucket

test:
  access_key_id: MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  secret_access_key: MY_SECRET_KEY
  bucket: myBucket

production:
  access_key_id: MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  secret_access_key: MY_SECRET_KEY
  bucket: myBucket


#app/views/my_model/_form.html.haml
= form_for @my_model_instance, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
  %fieldset
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
  %fieldset
    = f.label 'Attach Image'
    = f.file_field :image
  %fieldset
    = f.label :description
    = f.text_area :description
  %fieldset
    = f.submit 'Save', :class => 'button'
```

Comment: You're awesome. I could have swore I added 'gem 'paperclip'' to my gemfile and then ran bundle install; but it wasn't there. I did it again, and all is good! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**You get an error if you run on development mode, write this in terminal `rails s` to run development mode**

**this**

```
 :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/amazons3.yml",
```

**change to, for work correctly with Rails 3**

```
:s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/amazons3.yml",
```